# In Android system, hasNextLine() return false after reading the first line

Tags: android, java.util.scanner

In Android system, I wanted to read the file "/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats". But, if failed to read second line.
It was successful to read the first line. However, hasNextLine() returns false, which makes it impossible to read next lines.

The code is as follows:

```
    File statsFile = new File("/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats");
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(statsFile);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            Log.d(TAG, "hasNextLine(): " + scanner.hasNextLine());
```

Here is the stats file what I tried to read. The file looks like an one line on this post. But, each line ends with "0x0A" and it is displayed through 3 lines.

idx iface acct_tag_hex uid_tag_int cnt_set rx_bytes rx_packets tx_bytes tx_packets rx_tcp_bytes rx_tcp_packets rx_udp_bytes rx_udp_packets rx_other_bytes rx_other_packets tx_tcp_bytes tx_tcp_packets tx_udp_bytes tx_udp_packets tx_other_bytes tx_other_packets
2 wlan0 0x0 0 0 1129 10 2066 32 80 2 1049 8 0 0 0 0 530 8 1536 24
3 wlan0 0x0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: @ If you are reading from a file, why not use some 'Readers'

Answer (score 2):

Try using the good old reader classes:

```
try {
    File statsFile = new File("/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(statsFile)));

    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "readline(): " + line);
    }

    br.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```